`glab changelog generate` shows "no changes", what am I doing wrong?
I am using
glab changelog generate -v 1.0.0

to attempt to generate a changelog. I have written some commits with trailers like this:
git commit -m "chore: test trailers" --trailer "Changelog: changed"

When I execute the command above I get
## 1.1.1 (2024-08-05)

No changes.

I tried reading the docs, without success. They are not very detailed.
I am unclear on which branch the CLI uses, main or the current one?
If I specify a tag via flag, which commits get included in the changelogs? I would not know as I could never generate them.
I tried using the /.gitlab/changelog_config.yml from https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/.gitlab/changelog_config.yml without effect.
I would love to know how to configure my new repository, such as tags, releases and commits in order to see an output.
Git log shows my last commit as follows :
Author: Divide by zero <my@mail.com>
Date:   Mon Aug 5 14:25:00 2024 +0200

    chore: glab trailer test

    Changelog: feature


Have you pushed your changes to main ? The glab changelog generate command pulls from what is already pushed and generates the changelog from those commits, not the local commits.
